# How do I add individual server with individual user in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

For example we have 5 servers and 5 users
We need to add individual user to
individual server through Ansible playbook.

I have written playbook but it is adding all 5 users in all 5 servers.

But I need to add user1 in server1 and user 2 in server2 and so on..

Anybody know then please help me

Comment: Could you send the code of the task that doesn't do this?

Comment: https://github.com/satyamskic/example.git

This is code which I'm running currently but it is adding all users in all hosts.... You can modify this file and suggest me where i can use when conditions

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a explicit mapping between users and servers. At the end you need to have something like this dict:

```
config:
  - server1
    - user1
    - user2
  - server2
    - user2
    - user3
  - server3
    - user4
```

With this dictionary you can loop over all hosts and match the host with the item in serverX and when it matches, use the inner list to add the corresponding users with Ansible. The dictionary can be an external configuration file, that you read inside the playbook or what ever.

As an alternative, you can define hostvars per host in your inventory.

```
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ansible_host: 10....
      users:
        - user1
        - user2
    server2:
      ansible_host: 10....
      users:
        - user3
    ...
```

In that case you define it static and your playbook runs against the group "all" and iterates over the var "users" per host and configures that users.

I think, the problem is the "individual" in your question. You need to think about the base of this information, is is static or dynamic. Is it today something else then tomorrow...